# passing challenge (java i/0) try catch. i have passed all but one test case

Tags: java, exception

first : Java has built-in mechanism to handle exceptions. Using the try statement we can test a block of code for errors. The catch block contains the code that says what to do if exception occurs.

This problem will test your knowledge on try-catch block.

You will be given two integers x,y and  as input, you have to compute x/y . If  and  are not  bit signed integers or if  is zero, exception will occur and you have to report it. Read sample Input/Output to know what to report in case of exceptions.

---

i have passed all but one test case where it wants java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero for when the user inputs a 0. my catch outputs System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");
how can i pass the last test case?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    try{            
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input1 = scan.nextInt();
        int input2 = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(divideInput(input1,input2));
    }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");           
    }

 }

  public static int divideInput(int input1, int input2)
  {
     int sum;
     sum = input1 / input2;
     return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't tell unless we have the input. Are you certain there are two integers in the input stream?

Comment: Do you want to print all exception type in ` System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");` and looking for alternate way to print this statement?

Comment: sample in/out: Sample Input 1:

10
Hello
Sample Output 1:

java.util.InputMismatchException
Sample Input 2:

10
0
Sample Output 2:

java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Sample Input 3:

23.323
0
Sample Output 3:

java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: like i said it prints the appropriate output for 3 of the test cases however it doesnt catch the arithmetic error and doesnt output the error i need. thats why im a bit confused.

Comment: You are literally telling it to print "java.util.InputMismatchException" so that's what it's going to do.

Comment: is there a proper way to have it catch the problem, identify it, then output based of the correct condition? and thats what i thought.  btw everyone that has responded... It's appreciated.

Comment: _"If ? and ? are not bit signed integers or if ? is zero"_ -- why did you omit important information in the text?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching every exception in one block:

```
catch(Exception e){
    // stuff
}
```

You can split out specific types of exceptions.

```
catch(ArithmeticException e){
    // stuff for ArithmeticException 
}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    // stuff for InputMismatchException 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to catch the ArithmeticException.

What I'm seeing in your code should work, but probably the site is executing only the method divideInput(.., ..).

**I think you can wrap the code with try-catch block within divideInput method:**

```
public static int divideInput(int input1, int input2) {
    try {
        return input1 / input2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");
        throw new java.util.InputMismatchException(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Got it running and passing all of the test case.

---

```
`import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */



    try{   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input1 = scan.nextInt();
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(divideInput(input1,input2));
    }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.println("java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero");
}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
     System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");
}

    }
  public static int divideInput(int input1, int input2)
        {
         int sum;
         sum = input1 / input2;
          return sum;
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it like below:-

```
//just use any one of these three statement
e.printStackTrace();   
System.err.println(e.toString());
System.err.println(e.getMessage());
```